# File IO - Calculate Grades

Tags: file, python-3.x, file-io

I just started to learn how to read and write from files in python and we were asked to read from a file we'll call 'score.txt'. 'score.txt' looks something like this

Billy 0.03 74 0.03 79 0.03 72 0.03 69 0.03 81 0.03 75 0.03 73 0.03 70 0.08 75 0.08 73 0.25 82 0.25 71 0.10 28

Bob 0.03 84 0.03 79 0.03 87 0.03 90 0.03 85 0.03 82 0.03 86 0.03 83 0.08 87 0.08 89 0.25 82 0.25 84 0.10 80

Joe 0.03 66 0.03 63 0.03 89 0.03 65 0.03 57 0.03 70 0.03 64 0.03 67 0.08 65 0.08 62 0.25 70 0.25 61 0.10 27

Each line starts with a name, followed by the first value is the amount of the weight of the score, followed by the score itself. This repeats as many times as necessary, but the format will always be correct.

My final output needs to look something along the lines of this:

Billy:  70.68 - C

Bob:  83.86 - B

Joe:  61.84 - D

Class Average: 72.12

I'm honestly unsure how I even want to begin to tackle this problem. So far this is the code that I have, and all this does is creating a list with all of the information inside.

I know that I need to be able to remove the first index which I could use myList.pop(0), which would remove the name, but I'm not sure how I could multiply the first index, and the second index by each other, then continue onward.

```
def main():

    grade()

def grade():

    inFile = open("score.txt", "r")
    outFile = open("score_report.txt", "w")
    myList = []
    flag = True

    while flag:
        theLine = inFile.readline()
        if len(theLine) == 0:
            flag = False
        #outFile.write(theLine)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        myList.append(theLine)
    print(myList)

    inFile.close()
    outFile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start (untested) with a couple of pieces left for you.

```
with open("score.txt", "r") as imp, open("score_report.txt", "w") as out:
    n, class_sum = 0, 0
    for lime in imp:
        items = line.split()
        if not len(items) % 2:
            raise ValueError('line has even number of items')
        it = iter(items)
        name = next(it)  # cannot fail because odd number of items
        wt_score = 0
        for wt in it:
            wt_score += wt * next(it)  # ditto
        out.write(name, wt_score)  # plus grade
        n += 1
        class_sum += score
    # out.write( <class summary>)
```